# I don't know it kept looping where it isn't supposed to loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just stuck with some loop situation.
I was working with selenium, so... if it loops in a wrong place, usually it occurs an error with StaleElementReference or NoSuchElement error. And that's what I'm getting now.

A part of my code which has the problem is like this( I'll summarize it for you):

```
cc = 0
While True:
    print(cc)
    cc += 1

    if A == something:
        try:
            B
        except:
            C
    elif A == something_else:
        try:
            E
        except:
            F

#This is the problematic part

    else:
        answer = Success(z,name)
        print('check')

        if answer == 1:
            break
        elif answer == 2:
            print("flag1")
            shutil.move("\\Party_People\\HTML\\"+name+".html", "\\Party_People\\Misc")
            driver.get('http://cdb.chosun.com/search/db-people/i_common/index.jsp')
            print("flag2")
            time.sleep(0.7)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='이름']").send_keys(name)
            time.sleep(0.3)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='more2']").click()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='bodyarea']/div[@class='people2']/li")
            print("flag3")
            return 777

def Success(num, name):
    time.sleep(2)
    Download_html(name)


    print("다운로드한 HTML을 표시중입니다.")
    driver2.get(os.getcwd()+"\\Party_People\\HTML\\"+name+".html")
    print("네이버 인물검색에서 해당 인물 검색 결과를 표시중입니다.")
    driver3.get("https://people.search.naver.com/search.naver?sm=sbx_hty&where=nexearch&ie=utf8&query="+name+"&x=0&y=0")

    Final_Choice = input("해당 다운로드 결과가 맞다면 '1'을, 아니라면 '2'를 입력해주십시오.")
    return Final_Choice
```

And what happens is... after I input "2" for the Final_Choice which would be "answer", suddenly it just goes back and starts from the top. So "cc" prints "0" first, and then after I input "2", I got print of 'check' and then suddenly cc prints "1". Which means I didn't get any response from

```
        if answer == 1:
            break
        elif answer == 2:
            print("flag1")
            shutil.move("\\Party_People\\HTML\\"+name+".html", "\\Party_People\\Misc")
            driver.get('http://cdb.chosun.com/search/db-people/i_common/index.jsp')
            print("flag2")
            time.sleep(0.7)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='이름']").send_keys(name)
            time.sleep(0.3)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='more2']").click()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='bodyarea']/div[@class='people2']/li")
            print("flag3")
            return 777
```

'flag1, 2, 3' didn't show up. I wonder why it starts loop from the top at that point. I mean, isn't it supposed to start over unless I put 'continue' or just let the whole code inside of loof end? If you want to see the full code, I can share it with you but... since I'm not familiar with coding, it would be messy and clumsy to check.
Thank you in advance! Hope I got some help here as always...

Comment: Seems like you're comparing the return value of `input(...)` which is a string since you're on python3 to integers.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Geeez. I can't believe I made that mistake again. I'll try to fix it with your advice after my dinner done! Thank you Justin.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thank you so much Justin! Everything works fine now :)